# Working with large JSON files in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

My application loads quite a large amount of JSON data from a remote server (via URL) and processes it into smaller arrays before sending them to view.

My question is where to place the code that loads and processes the data, so that it is processed only once when the app is loaded?

How would I go about displaying the loading gif in the view while this is happening?

Comment: when you say 'the app is loaded' you mean the server is starting? or the session is starting? is there a user involved in the loading of the JSON?

Comment: When the visitor first launches the site. Now the code is in the controller and it is reloaded every time I refresh the page. The data changes probably only once a week or so, so this is not necessary.

Comment: Then why don't you do it offline with a crobjob or something?

Comment: @UriAgassi you are right it will be good to use cron job or rescue to process those file in the back-end